# How to create a simple map using JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashmap

How can you create the JavaScript/JQuery equivalent of this Java code:

```
Map map = new HashMap(); //Doesn't not have to be a hash map, any key/value map is fine
map.put(myKey1, myObj1);
map.put(myKey2, myObj2); //Repeat n times

function Object get(k) {
    return map.get(k);
}
```

Answer (score 304, accepted):

Edit: Out of date answer, ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) standard javascript has a Map implementation, read here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

```
var map = new Object(); // or var map = {};
map[myKey1] = myObj1;
map[myKey2] = myObj2;

function get(k) {
    return map[k];
}

//map[myKey1] == get(myKey1);
```

Comment: Updated my answer to use a `new Object()` instead of `new Array()`. See [this article](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/)

Comment: How  can we provide a root node here?

Comment: How can we remove a key value payer from the map ?

Comment: @Shikha Most efficient way would simply be to put (key, null) and then check if your value is null. Otherwise, check how to remove items in an array (using javascript function splice)

Comment: Is myKey1 a variable? Is it a string? There are no quotes around it. Can there be quotes around it if I want that as the key?

Comment: This answer is now out of date as Map does exist now (yay!), read the following: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: The problem of the official implementation is that is doesn't allow custom equality (it only uses ===) so I still have to write my own.

Answer (score 80):

Just use plain objects:

```
var map = { key1: "value1", key2: "value2" }
function get(k){
  return map[k];
}
```

Comment: The keys shouldn't be specified as strings, i.e. without quotes

Answer (score 25):

```
function Map() {
    this.keys = new Array();
    this.data = new Object();

    this.put = function (key, value) {
        if (this.data[key] == null) {
            this.keys.push(key);
        }
        this.data[key] = value;
    };

    this.get = function (key) {
        return this.data[key];
    };

    this.remove = function (key) {
        this.keys.remove(key);
        this.data[key] = null;
    };

    this.each = function (fn) {
        if (typeof fn != 'function') {
            return;
        }
        var len = this.keys.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var k = this.keys[i];
            fn(k, this.data[k], i);
        }
    };

    this.entrys = function () {
        var len = this.keys.length;
        var entrys = new Array(len);
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            entrys[i] = {
                key: this.keys[i],
                value: this.data[i]
            };
        }
        return entrys;
    };

    this.isEmpty = function () {
        return this.keys.length == 0;
    };

    this.size = function () {
        return this.keys.length;
    };
}
```

Comment: At least, put all those methods on the prototype.

Comment: @Adshi: [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript)

Comment: `this.data[key] = null` won't delete the property; it just sets its value to `null`. You should use `delete this.data[key]` instead.

Comment: At entry function,  you should change like this. 
entrys[i] = {
                key: this.keys[i],
                value: this.data[i]
            }; ->  entrys[i] = {
                key: this.keys[i],
                value: this.data[this.keys[i]]
            }; -

Comment: @Bergi this < prototype < local scope (currying), believe me, life is much easier when you don't have to deal with leaking variables and changable scope.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY: I have no idea what currying has to do with this, but prototype methods don't leak variables or have changeable scope either. They do have a late-bound `this` context, but that's a feature not a problem.

Comment: @Bergi you need `this` to access variables with `prototype` methods, it's not really an option. The only way to avoid this is with _closures_ (not currying, oops), which has the additional benefit of private variables. This nearly makes the prototype obsolete, since closures remove most performance gained by using prototypes in the first place.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY: So you mean properties, not variables?

Comment: @Bergi OK, OK, I never program in JS anymore, call it whatever you want :P

Comment: "this.keys.remove is not a function", arrays doesn't have such function, you have to create it also:

Array.prototype.remove = function(o) {
 var index = this.indexOf(o);
 
 if (index > -1) {
  this.splice(index, 1);
  return true;
 }
 
 return false;
};

Answer (score 23):

*This is an old question, but because the existing answers could be very dangerous, I wanted to leave this answer for future folks who might stumble in here...*

The answers based on using an Object as a HashMap are broken and can cause extremely nasty consequences if you use anything other than a String as the key. The problem is that Object properties are coerced to Strings using the .toString method. This can lead to the following nastiness:

```
function MyObject(name) {
  this.name = name;
};
var key1 = new MyObject("one");
var key2 = new MyObject("two");

var map = {};
map[key1] = 1;
map[key2] = 2;
```

If you were expecting that Object would behave in the same way as a Java Map here, you would be rather miffed to discover that map only contains *one* entry with the String key `[object Object]`:

```
> JSON.stringify(map);
{"[object Object]": 2}
```

This is clearly **not** a replacement for Java's HashMap. Bizarrely, given it's age, Javascript does not currently have a general purpose map object. There is hope on the horizon, though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map although a glance at the Browser Compatability table there will show that this isn't ready to used in general purpose web apps yet.

In the meantime, the best you can do is:

- Deliberately use Strings as keys. I.e. use explicit strings as keys rather than relying on the implicit .toString-ing of the keys you use.
- Ensure that the objects you are using as keys have a well-defined .toString() method that suits your understanding of uniqueness for these objects.
- If you cannot/don't want to change the .toString of the key Objects, when storing and retrieving the entries, convert the objects to a string which represents your understanding of uniqueness. E.g. `map[toUniqueString(key1)] = 1`

Sometimes, though, that is not possible. If you want to map data based on, for example File objects, there is no reliable way to do this because the attributes that the File object exposes are not enough to ensure its uniqueness. (You may have two File objects that represent different files on disk, but there is no way to distinguish between them in JS in the browser). In these cases, unfortunately, all that you can do is refactor your code to eliminate the need for storing these in a may; perhaps, by using an array instead and referencing them exclusively by index.

Answer (score 18):

```
var map = {'myKey1':myObj1, 'mykey2':myObj2};
// You don't need any get function, just use
map['mykey1']
```

Comment: For whatever reason, we can also do: `var myKey = "myKey1"` and then `var map = { [myKey] : myObj1}`

Answer (score 6):

If you're not restricted to JQuery, you can use the prototype.js framework.  It has a class called Hash:  You can even use JQuery & prototype.js together.  Just type jQuery.noConflict();

```
var h = new Hash();
h.set("key", "value");
h.get("key");
h.keys(); // returns an array of keys
h.values(); // returns an array of values
```