# Passing hashmap from javascript to servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashmap

I created a simplehashmap using the accepted solution in this question:
[How to create a simple map using JavaScript/JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246980/how-to-create-a-simple-map-using-javascript-jquery)

I however need to send this var to a servlet and retrieve them onto a Java `HashMap`. How do I do that.

The key is a string while the value is an array, say like:

```
`[1,'apple,orange, banana'],[2,'apple,peach, banana']` ...
```

I need the keys 1,2 and the array loaded onto a Java `HashMap`.

I tried to post it using jquery.  where selectedrows is my map

```
$.post(url, { id: selectedrows });
```

Comment: I edited the post to include my jquery .post command, but how do i identify it as a map on the java side and retrieve both key and value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I creates a JSON string and then sent it via an ajax post to the servlet and build the HashMap there.