# HashMap objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loop through JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object)
>   [Get array of object’s keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763125/get-array-of-objects-keys)

Is there a way to use hashmaps in javascript. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246980/how-to-create-a-simple-map-using-javascript-jquery) page which shows one way of having hashmaps in javascript. Based on that I am storing the data as below:

```
var map = new Object();
map[myKey1] = myObj1;
map[myKey2] = myObj2;

function get(k) {
   return map[k];
}
```

But I want the keySet (all the keys) of the `map` object just like it is done in Java (`map.keySet();`).

Can anyone show me how can get all the keys present in this object?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
for (var key in map) {
  if (map.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    alert(key + " -> " + map[key]);
  }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/684692/106261

actually [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8763227/106261) is much better :

```
var keys = Object.keys(map);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `for..in` statement:

```
for (var key  in map) {
    return map[key];
}
```

Comment: This will just return the first value and not the keyset.

Comment: This will also return things from the prototype, which is inconvenient when using this as a general purpose map.