# how to get java Hashmap object using javascript

Tags: javascript, hashmap

`restContext.getRequestHeaders();`
I am passing HashMap of type HashMap(String,String)  to request Header as shown in the abstract code.

```
var headers=restContext.getRequestHeaders();
for( key in headers){
  query.replace(''#id#'',headers[key]);
  query= query.concat(headers[key]);
}
```

Comment: As a developer tip, always keep your indentation clean. This is a mess.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911853/hashmap-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HashMap objects in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911853/hashmap-objects-in-javascript)