# How to do an entry in javascript map from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rss

I am modifying my previous question since I feel this problem is closely related to putting an entry in map from ajax call. There is nothing wrong with Map.

**EDIT** :-

I am populating a map of feeds in following ways where key represent url and value represent feeds;

```
channelMap.each(function(key,url,n){
    loadFeedFor(url,10);
    console.debug(feedMap);
});
:
function loadFeedFor(url,maxposts){
     var gurl = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&callback=?&q="+url;
     if(maxposts != null) gurl += "&num="+maxposts;
      $.getJSON(gurl, function(){})
     .done(function(data){
         feeds = data.responseData.feed;
         feedMap.put(url,feeds);
      });
 }
```

But it is not working. I guess I would have to use Deffered for this problem but have no idea how.

I am using map from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15739569/453767).

I tried doing same thing in another way where I am not using map. I am calling following function with different 3 rss feeds url;

```
function rssfeedsetup(feedId,feedurl,feedlimit){
    var feedpointer=new google.feeds.Feed(feedurl); //Google Feed API method
    feedpointer.setNumEntries(feedlimit); //Google Feed API method
    feedpointer.load(function(response){
        console.log(response.feed);
        return setTimeout(displayFeed(response.feed,feedId), 3000);
    }); //Google Feed API method
}
```

console prints all feeds properly (25 entries). But feeds actually appear on page are 
always less. Even delay is not helping me.

Comment: Are you waiting for `$.jGFeed` to complete before trying to use the map?

Comment: nope. And I guess this is only the problem. How can I do this?

Comment: Is it possibly a variable scope issue? What does console.debug(some key) and console.debug(channelMap) print if called in the anonymous function?

Comment: they gets printed properly but same as "in calls" gets printed, after "out of call". console.debug(channelMap) prints `Map {keys: Array[i], data: Object, put: function, get: function, remove: function…};` where i is incremented value.

Comment: I have resolved the issue of executing next function before finishing the call of `$.jGFeed`. Still problem persist :(

Comment: Can someKey be null? In the provided code of put function the array is not filled if it is null

Comment: WTH is that code supposed to do? Currently you're returning a Deferred which resolves with an empty string after a random time (up to 4s). The `$.jGFeed` and the `channelMap` are completely unrelated

Comment: Why don't you use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4247008/1048572) for the map?