# How to get data from objects of an array

Tags: javascript

I have a data structure like below...

```
[
  {name: "coke",  price:"10"},
  {name: "sprit", price: "20"}
]
```

My question is how do I get the price based on its name?
for example, how do get coke price?

Comment: Do you know how to loop over an array?

Comment: You could use a Map, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246980/how-to-create-a-simple-map-using-javascript-jquery .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can do it with the loop function

```
    var dataArr = [
      {name: "coke",  price:"10"},
      {name: "sprit", price: "20"}
    ];

    for(var i=0;i<dataArr.length;i++){
         if(dataArr[i].name == "coke"){
             console.log(dataArr[i].price); // prints 10
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the array using any looping method you like (such as `for`, `Array.prototype.forEach`, or `Array.prototype.filter`) and test the value of the name property of each object until you find the one you want. Then get the value property of it.

Answer (score 2):

Just loop through the array and get the object property.

```
var arr = [{name: "coke",  price:"10"},{name: "sprit", price: "20"}];

for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
  if(arr[i].name === "coke"){
       console.log(arr[i].price);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
(arr.find(function(item){ return item.name === 'coke'}) || {}).price;
```

or you can find all items named "coke":

```
arr.filter(function(item){
    return item.name === 'coke';
})
```

Comment: arr.map(function(item){ return item.price; });

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [{
  name: "coke",
  price: "10"
}, {
  name: "sprit",
  price: "20"
}];

function getValue(data, name) {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].name === name) {
      return data[i].price;
    }
  }
}

var value = getValue(data, 'coke');
alert(value);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ej5ofsxm/

You can loop through the array and get price based on name.