# jQuery HashMap Implementation: Missing : after Property ID Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to dynamically populate a HashMap in jQuery, and am following this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4247012/1005607    Orig Question: [How to create a simple map using JavaScript/JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246980/how-to-create-a-simple-map-using-javascript-jquery)

I need to add a hash entry where the key comes from an array item, and the value is a variable. But I'm getting an error. What's wrong? This should be equivalent to populating `"item2" -> 2` in the HashMap. I would be able to get `2` by invoking `laneMap.get("item2")`.

```js
var laneMap = {};

var eventIDs = [];
eventIDs.push('item1');
eventIDs.push('item2');

var currlane = 2;

laneMap.push({eventIDs[1] : currlane });
```

Comment: Side note, what you are calling a HashMap is just an Object in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add key/value pair using `push`. There are two ways of doing it
Using dot notation:

```
obj.key3 = "value3";
```

Using square bracket notation:

```
obj["key3"] = "value3";
```

```js
var laneMap = {};

var eventIDs = [];
eventIDs.push('item1');
eventIDs.push('item2');
   
var currlane = 2;
laneMap.key = currlane-1;
laneMap[eventIDs[1]] = currlane ;
console.log(laneMap);
```

**P.S.**- You can't use `[]` in `dot` notation

Answer (score 2):

You can only use `.push` with an array.  Here's how to assign a dynamic object property:

`laneMap[eventIDs[1]] = currlane;`